# Cross Compile a automake project?

Tags: c++, c, linux, arm, cross-compiling

I am developing an application for `enocean`. I am able to compile it for my Host system. I want to cross compile it for `beaglebone black` running `openwrt`. I have cross compiler and all other libraries. I am not sure how to change the existing configure, Makefiles to cross-compile it.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to change anything. autotools comes with full cross-compilation support.

Just pass the proper `--host=` flag for your target architecture, e.g.:

```
./configure --host arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

This will look for toolchain programs with the given prefix (in the above case, it would look e.g. for a compiler `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`) in your current `$PATH`. Most cross-compiling toolchains should automatically adhere to this convention.

See also the [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html)

Comment: How can i specify the path having compiler binaries with `host` command line argument?

Comment: Looks like i am able to compile it!

Comment: Can you comment on which options to specify to `configure` so that i will link to my embedded libraries (not my build system libraries)?

Comment: i've updated the question to include information about your first comment. i will not comment on the "which options to specify" question/comment as this is a) unrelated to your original question (hint: ask a new question) and b) totally specific to your project (so i consider it impossible to answer generically)